# How to convert a string to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a `string` like this:

```
$str = "<div>
            <b>
                <label>Company-Name : Anything</label>
            </b>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>
                <label>First-Name : Alex</label>
            </b>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>
                <label>Cell-Phone : 035123913</label>
            </b>
        </div>";
```

Now I want this array:

```
$arr = array ("Company-Name"=>"Anything",
              "First-Name"=>"Alex",
              "Cell-Phone"=>"035123913");
```

How can I do that?

---

As far as I realized by searching, there is a function which removes all html tags:

```
strip_tags($str);
```

I think the above function is a clue. Also there is two characters which are constant: `\n` and `:`. I think we can use them to explode the result. *(however I'm not sure, maybe I'm wrong)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the strip_tags approach, but here is a regex take:

```
$str = "<div>
            <b>
                <label>Company-Name : Anything</label>
            </b>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>
                <label>First-Name : Alex</label>
            </b>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>
                <label>Cell-Phone : 035123913</label>
            </b>
        </div>";

preg_match_all('/<label>(.*)<\/label>/', $str, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    $parts = explode(':', $match);
    $results[trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
}
var_dump($results);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  'Company-Name' => string 'Anything' (length=8)
  'First-Name' => string 'Alex' (length=4)
  'Cell-Phone' => string '035123913' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a double `explode`.

```
$str = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$arr = array();
foreach ($str as $val) {
  $arr[] = explode(":", $val);
}
```

You might need to `trim()` in all the cases I guess.

Comment: I think you have to remove all html tags. Here is the output of your code https://3v4l.org/dqrCg

Comment: @stack I thought you did that using `strip_tags()`. Man, we can't spoon feed you! We can guide you to write code.

Comment: Yes I can use it, thank you, I just mentioned to that point because I wanted when other users use your code, then see a desired result. anyway ok thanks again. +1

Comment: @stack Once you get it right, feel free to edit my answer bro! :) You have all rights! `:)`

Comment: To be honest, that's scare for me to edit your answer, who has 80K rep `:)` .

Comment: @stack I just gave you the full freedom. Doesn't mean if I have 80k Rep, I am a master! And those with less are not! `:)`

Comment: @stack This is an open community, where everyone has equal rights to talk and do stuff, *as long as it doesn't hurt anyone*. That's the main point.

Comment: @stack If you are still afraid, LoL, send me the code, and I will edit my answer! Haha... :)

Comment: I'm working your idea .. [still there is some small problem](https://3v4l.org/Rl7At),  I will edit your solution when I solve them.

Comment: @stack Come to chat. You missed the `trim($str)` and it should be everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem, built upon the previous answer by @Praveen Kumar

```
$str = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$arr = [];

foreach ($str as $val) {
    $pos=strpos($val, ":");
    if ($pos !== false)
    {
        $arr[] = explode(":", strip_tags($val));
    }

}

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
   $final_array[trim($value[0])] = trim($value[1]);
}

var_dump($final_array);
```

Output

```
   array (size=3)
  'Company-Name' => string 'Anything' (length=8)
  'First-Name' => string 'Alex' (length=4)
  'Cell-Phone' => string '035123913' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to obtain your desired result (without stripping tags), is to use a regular expression:

```
preg_match_all( "{<label>([^:]+) +: +([^<]+)</label>}", $str, $matches );
```

By this way, in `$matches` array, you will obtain this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <label>Company-Name : Anything</label>
            [1] => <label>First-Name : Alex</label>
            [2] => <label>Cell-Phone : 035123913</label>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company-Name
            [1] => First-Name
            [2] => Cell-Phone
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Anything
            [1] => Alex
            [2] => 035123913
        )

)
```

Comment: Ha ha... Nice one, we need to then map it with each other.

Comment: @PraveenKumar oh, yes